# Creating a user control object in runtime

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

please help me on creating a user control object in runtime using createobject function or whatever better function in vb.net.

here is my code:

```
Dim b As New Security.Sec_Role
b.Name = "Sec_Role" 
b.visible = true
```

but i want to use this code:

```
dim b as object
b = createobject("Security.Sec_Role")
```

but it always return an error:

```
Cannot create ActiveX component.
```

**EDIT**: i figure it out..thanks a lot..i use this codes:

```
Dim asm As System.Reflection.Assembly = Assembly.Load("Security")
Dim b As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(asm.GetType("Security.Sec_Role"))
```

Comment: i have a 2 projects, one is the main and the other one is a collection of usercontrols i also created. the names of the user control is save in a database so i can easily call the object. but how i can create it in my main project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an .Net UserControl you will not be able to use `CreateObject` unless it has been exposed as a Com object according to the MSDN page for [CreateObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9k08y5.aspx). Using New would be the proper way to create a .Net UserControl.

From above link:

> Creates and returns a reference to a COM object. CreateObject cannot
>   be used to create instances of classes in Visual Basic unless those
>   classes are explicitly exposed as COM components.

From this [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/netfxbcl/thread/5C81DCA2-F2DE-456F-843B-302026C5C02D) try something like this using [`System.Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx#Y0):

```
Dim oType As System.Type = Type.GetType("MyNamespace.ClassName")
Dim obj = System.Activator.CreateInstance(oType)
```

Comment: How many different usercontrols are we talking about? If it is a reasonable number try creating a function that has a select statement that returns your object.

Comment: its about 30 controls...and can also add later...but to create/call it and place in the form is my problem.

Comment: oType returns null...why is that sir?

Answer (score 1):

.Net classes are not ActiveX controls.
You can't do that.

You may be looking for Reflection or a dictionary.

Comment: can you help me to create that control?

Comment: because..the control is based on the data in the database i retrieve...for example..i choose the sec_role in the database..then it will call the control a created whose name is sec_role.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx):

```
Dim b as object
b = Activator.CreateInstance(Nothing, "Sec_Role")
```

It will be easiest if this method is in the assembly which has the controls. Otherwise, you will need to provide the assembly name in the first parameter.

Comment: can you explain more further detail sir?

Comment: it returns an error

"Could not load type 'Sec_Role' from assembly 'SimSolInc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

Comment: do you think it require a constructor? but i don't know how to make one.

Comment: @dave: the problem is that if you are executing this code from a different assembly than the one the control lives in, then you need to specify the assembly name in the first parameter, something like `CreateInstance("Security",` but you may need more details than that. It would be easier if this code code live in the same project as the controls.

Comment: i try this code,

b = Activator.CreateInstance("Security", "Sec_Role")

where Security is the assembly name and Sec_Role is the type name..but still it return this error, 

"Could not load type 'Sec_Role' from assembly 'Security, Version=1.0.4387.23466, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."